# how to call operator + in operator +=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it right to define operator += in this way ?!

```
void operator +=(const BigNumber& other)
{
    *this=(*this) + other;
}
```

In a class like this :

```
class BigNumber
{
public:
   //....
    BigNumber operator +(const BigNumber& other)
    {
        return sum(other);
    }

  //....
}
```

Comment: See [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) for a definitive guide to all aspects of operator overloading, including the question you asked. Specifically, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/1227469) and scroll down to "binary arithmetic operators"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. But the right way is to implement `operator+` in terms of `operator+=`:

```
struct foo
{
    int value;

    foo& operator+=( const foo& other )
    {
        value += foo.value;
        return *this ;
    }

    friend foo operator+( foo lhs , const foo& rhs )
    {
        return lhs += rhs;
    }
};
```

### Why?

First of all, the binary `operator+()` shouldn't be defined as member function instead of free function. This allows you to implement addition where the first parameter is not a `foo`. The common idiom is to declare it `friend` inside the class to ride over encapsulation.

Second, **this way provides a coherent, maintainible, and efficient interface**.

#### Coherency:

If you implement a `+=` operation, the user spects (Except in rare cases) the type provides a binary addition too. Implementing `+` with `+=` provides this ensuring that the behavior of the two operations is coherent.

#### Maintainability:

You have implemented `+` using `+=`, so **the code which really performs the addition is written only once**. If you need to change the operation in the future you have to change one code only, and if it has a bug that bug is in one site only. Reducing code duplication is a good practice in general.

#### Efficiency:

The way the `operator+()` is written allows the compiler to easily elide copies, boosting the performance of the binary addition.

The idiom used is *"copy first operand, operate on it, return the copy"*. So **the compiler can easily perform a return value optimization (RVO)**. Also, it passes the first operand by value instead of copying the operand by hand inside the function. This allows the compiler to **perform more copy elisions when the first operand is an rvalue** (Let the compiler decide when and how to copy).

Comment: What the OP did is right. I agree that the usual way to do it is to implement `operator+` in terms of `operator+=`, but both approaches are "right". We do not know the context...

Comment: @jbgs Agree. I have changed *No* to *Yes, but*.

Comment: @Manu343726: You actually do **not** need `operator+` to be declared as `friend` here, since it only relies on the `public` interface of the class.

Comment: @MatthieuM. thats true. I was only providing the general methodology.

Comment: @Manu343726: It actually also works in general. Compound operators need be members, but other operators rarely need to.

Comment: @MatthieuM. except if you use things like the Barton-Nackman trick to implement that operators, which is what I usually do by default.

Comment: @Manu343726: Ah, but then that's a totally other requirement; and a different beast too. If executed correctly (such as with Boost.Operators) the `friend` operators are declared in a stateless base class, and since friendship is not inherited they need not be inspected for invariant corruption.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it your way:

```
BigNumber& operator +=(const BigNumber& other)
{
    *this=(*this) + other;
    return *this;
}
```

The usual approach is the opposite way:

```
// Note a is no const reference
BigNumber operator + (BigNumber a, const BigNumber& b)
{
    return a += b;
}
```

A reasoning for your approach might be memory allocation.